# Unit Testing Failed - AccordionComponent

Tags: angular, unit-testing

I was importing `AccordionModule` inside module. But with "`ng test`", I'm getting below error in console-

```
Error: StaticInjectorError[AccordionComponent]: 
  StaticInjectorError[AccordionComponent]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AccordionComponent!
```

I already tried to import it inside `spec.ts` file and inside `component.ts` file, but still this error is coming.

Spec file:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [AccordionModule.forRoot()],
        declarations: [CBenefitComponent], providers: [DataService]
    }).compileComponents();
}));
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CBenefitComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance; fixture.detectChanges();
});

fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

And the CAFDetailModule :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms'; 
import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion'; 
@NgModule({ 
    imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule, AccordionModule.forRoot() 
    ], 
exports: [AccordionModule], 
}) 
export class CAFDetailModule { 
    constructor(){ 
        console.log('detail module loaded'); } 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code so that we get a better understanding on what is happening

Comment: 1. spec.ts file:

beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports:[ AccordionModule.forRoot()
      ],
      declarations: [ CBenefitComponent ],
      
      providers:[DataService]
                
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CBenefitComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  fit('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

Comment: Its not readable. Can you edit your question and paste the code there

Comment: and which accodion module are you using? Material ?

Comment: import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { AccordionModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/accordion';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      CommonModule,
      AccordionModule.forRoot()
   
    ],

    exports: [AccordionModule],
    
  })
  export class CAFDetailModule {

    constructor(){
      console.log('detail module loaded');
    }
  }

Comment: No, I'm not using Material. ngx-bootstrap/accordion I'm using

Comment: What do you have in `CBenefitComponent`?

Comment: I'm using accordion-group in HTML file. Else I don't have any special in component file. Error I'm getting during unit testing in Karma browser.